# How to view linux kernel logs live?

Tags: linux-kernel, logging

I have a kernel module logging input of some sensor while I work with it. I want to see if there is a command that outputs /var/log/messages (for example) but waits for more logs to come. That is, some program like `dmesg` except that it stays on and keeps printing newly-come logs.

Comment: Of course, I can always write a user space program, and read the value from some shared memory or /proc file etc, but I am just asking this question out of curiosity.

Comment: Why "online" in the title?

Comment: @eric, some people would say "view it in realtime". But realtime has a precise meaning and this is not it. Online is the word used to mean right then and there, but without time guarantees. For example "this robot is making these decisions online" when it's doing it "on the fly", but it's not realtime.

Comment: "realtime" is better indeed, and "live" or "as they're generated" or "log stream" is even better. There are many options available.

Comment: @eric, like I said realtime is wrong (although a common mistake), but I could go with live. I see how online would be confusing outside the robotics world.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried `tail -F`, eg.

```
tail -F /var/log/messages
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I wanted. I read the man page for `tail` but the part for `-f` was not at all understandable to me.

Comment: @Shahbaz : Be careful if you are looking at a file that is `log rotated`, i.e. logs are automatically archived, like syslog.0, syslog.1.gz etc.. As soon as the file you watching is rotated, you won't see any new lines. You have to restart tail -f. (At least this is the case on my system)

Comment: @Xavier T. Thanks. I was just doing this for a small test however to see if my driver worked

Comment: You can of course use the `tail -F` command which watches for changed/rotated files and continues to watch the file with the given name.

Answer (score 5):

Two more modern methods:

```
dmesg -w
```

On systems with systemd `journalctl` is also of interest:

```
journalctl --system -f
```

Comment: dmesg -w works on ubuntu 22

Answer (score 3):

You can:

- execute dmesg every second: `while true; do dmesg -c; sleep 1; done`
- print everything appended to /var/log/messages: `tail -f /var/log/messages`
- dump the logs on the serial port and read them on another PC. You will need to add to your kernel boot parameters: `console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty0 ignore_loglevel` and remove `quiet`

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
 cat /proc/kmsg
```

By this way you could get all kernel messages when they come